# Reusing ReactJS Button component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to find a way to re-use a button component which it needs to be used in other parts of my project.

## The current `<Button />` code is:

```
class Cover extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {isFollowing: false};
  } 

  toggleFollow (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({isFollowing: !this.state.isFollowing});
  }

render() {

    var followClass = this.state.isFollowing? 'active': '';
    return (
        <Button className="connect-btn" href="#">Connect</Button>
        <Button className={`follow-btn ${followClass}`} href="#" onClick={this.toggleFollow.bind(this)}>Follow</Button>

    );
  }
}
```

I need to do this for the `connect-btn` as well. It's turning out to be a mess when I duplicate the code used for the other button. It would be great if anybody could give me a solution. I just starting out with ReactJs and not very good. Thanks

Comment: My strategy for things like this is to find a module that already does it, and either us it, or use it as a reference to create my own. Here is robust example of how awesomely flexible you can make a react button component. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-button

Comment: Aside from your original question, I am curious if React is not throwing you an error for trying to return 2 components from within the `render` function instead of what it recommends i.e. to return only 1 component? That 1 component / element can have children of course.

Comment: You can use propTypes to define the text/on-off state of your button, and then simply pass them down to your button code in a parent element

Comment: You need to wrap the two button components, e.g. inside a `<span></span>`, which wraps the two components inside the `return( )`